# SF2 - My mp3 download link doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, header, mp3

I want to create a link "Download this mp3 file" but I have an error in my crontroller and I doesn't know why...

My file is in /tmp/yvm-download/

```
public function downloadAction($file)
    {
        # YoutubeDomwloader object
        $YoutubeDownloader = $this->container->get('dimi_yvm.youtubedownloader');


        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(file_get_contents($YoutubeDownloader->_download_directory . $file . '.mp3'));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
        $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename=' . $file . '.mp3');
         
        return $response;
    }
```

My error:

```
FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/site.com/main.site.com/Symfony2/src/Dimi/YvmBundle/Controller/HomeController.php line 74
```

Thanks you all.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, I give you the correct code to download files:

```
public function downloadAction($file)
{
 $response = new Response();
 $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'mime/type');
 $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=' . $file);
 $response->setContent($content);
 return $response;
}
```

Thanks you all for you help ! :)